# rails: custom validation for colour hash format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, format

for example one may set a format for email
such as

> EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z)0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i

I cannot get the syntax correct for a colour hash.
I want to make sure the user enters a hash followed by 6 characters(numbers/letters)

eg `#ff3u7a`

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out Rubular? http://rubular.com/

I believe this should work. I tried it out on a number of strings and got all positive results, but let me know what you get:

```
/^\#(\d|[a-z]){6}$/
```

Case insensitive:

```
/^\#(\d|[a-z]){6}$/i
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! Your A Life Saver!

Comment: You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`. Consider what your regex will do with `"#111111\npancakes"`.

Comment: can anyone help with this format. exactly like this `sauces/sauces_text.png` so everything in that string is exact, except for text which is simply alphabet letters lowercase?

Comment: Hmm It means you could have #GQUZWY, which is not hexadecimal (base 16). shoudn't it be more like `/^\#(\d|[a-f]){6}$/` ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: I think you mean `/\A#\h{6}\z/`, yours will still gladly accept nonsense like `"#111111\npancakes"`.

Comment: @muistooshort makes an excellent point regarding using `\A` and `\z`. As for @MrYoshiji's comment, I agree with you, and perhaps I should have gone further with my answer, but I decided to leave the rest to OP.